# In ASP.NET MVC 3, what class does Views and Partial Views inherit from?

Tags: view, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC 3, what class doe Views and Partial Views inherit from and can the class (presumably it's a class somewhere) be inherited from to extend functionality.

For example, the default LogOnPartial control has the following (using Razor syntax)

```
Welcome <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>!
```

Where is the Context object exposed. What class makes that available to the partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28VS.98%29.aspx In older versions of razor it was required to add the `@inherits` but newer versions don't.